# Change the Value field to percentage field in codeigniter OSPOS

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: add new giftcard]

This is add new gift page in OSPOS in CodeIGniter . there are four fields in that gifcard_id, person_id, giftcard_number, value I want Change the Value Field to Percentage of total price of the items that customer bought . the items are stored in another table.  How can i do that ?

my model

```
/*
    Gets gift card value
    */
    public function get_giftcard_value($giftcard_number)
    {
        if( !$this->exists($this->get_giftcard_id($giftcard_number)) )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        $this->db->from('giftcards');
        $this->db->where('giftcard_number', $giftcard_number);

        return $this->db->get()->row()->value;
    }

    /*
    Updates gift card value
    */
    public function update_giftcard_value($giftcard_number, $value)
    {
        $this->db->where('giftcard_number', $giftcard_number);
        $this->db->update('giftcards', array('value' => $value));
    }
```

My Controller

```
public function save($giftcard_id = -1)
    {
        $giftcard_number = $this->input->post('giftcard_number');

        if($giftcard_id == -1 && trim($giftcard_number) == '')
        {
            $giftcard_number = $this->Giftcard->generate_unique_giftcard_name($this->input->post('value'));
        }

        $giftcard_data = array(
            'record_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'giftcard_number' => $giftcard_number,
            'value' => parse_decimals($this->input->post('value')),
            'person_id' => $this->input->post('person_id') == '' ? NULL : $this->input->post('person_id')
        );

        if($this->Giftcard->save($giftcard_data, $giftcard_id))
        {
            $giftcard_data = $this->xss_clean($giftcard_data);

            //New giftcard
            if($giftcard_id == -1)
            {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'message' => $this->lang->line('giftcards_successful_adding') . ' ' .
                                $giftcard_data['giftcard_number'], 'id' => $giftcard_data['giftcard_id']));
            }
            else //Existing giftcard
            {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'message' => $this->lang->line('giftcards_successful_updating') . ' ' .
                                $giftcard_data['giftcard_number'], 'id' => $giftcard_id));
            }
        }
        else //failure
        {
            $giftcard_data = $this->xss_clean($giftcard_data);

            echo json_encode(array('success' => FALSE, 'message' => $this->lang->line('giftcards_error_adding_updating') . ' ' .
                            $giftcard_data['giftcard_number'], 'id' => -1));
        }
    }
```